# mount command hang with virtio 9p with QEMU build on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, qemu, file-sharing, virtio

When I am using virtio-9p-pci device with qemu 6.1 build on CentOS 7.3(kernel 3.10.0) to transfer files from HOST to Guest. Command to run QEMU with virtio device ::

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
   -m 4G \
   -M q35 \
   -hda qcow2_path.qcow2 \
   -enable-kvm \
   -fsdev local,id=a1,security_model=none,path=path_of_host_directory \
   -device virtio-9p-pci,fsdev=a1,mount_tag=test
```

After Guest OS boot up I am running mount command. It gets hang and Virtual Machine gets freeze. Mount Command:

```
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio test /home/ -oversion=9p2000.L
```

I tied to run mount command, but it gets hang. I was expecting to see the host directory in guest after completion of mount command.

I tried with Centos 8.5 (kernel 4.18.0), Everything works fine.